# @font-face stopped working on certain fonts

Tags: css, font-face

I used @font-face on my website for 2 fonts. 
One of them stopped working - I checked everything, tried different syntax but nothing brings it back. 
Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'gotham';
src:url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.eot) format('eot');
src:url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.ttf) format('truetype'), url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gotham-book.otf) format('opentype'), url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.woff) format('woff'),  url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.eot?iefix) format('embedded-opentype');       
}

@font-face
{
font-family: 'yank';
src: url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/yank.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

The "Yank" font still works perfectly. using chrome for QA.

website: www.odednaaman.com

any ideas?

Thanks, 
Oded

Answer (score 1):

The `src` should be only once but you're having two times in your first @font-face. So, use this:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'gotham';
src:url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.eot) format('eot'),
    url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gotham-book.otf) format('opentype'),
    url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.woff) format('woff'),
    url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/gothambook.eot?iefix) format('embedded-opentype');       
}

@font-face
{
font-family: 'yank';
src: url(http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/yank.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the console of Chrome:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://www.odednaaman.com/fonts/ygothambook.woff

So it seems that you need to upload the .woff file.